# Google Analytics 4 custom data to track app tenant and user activity

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Somewhat new to GA.  I think I want custom dimensions and metrics but unclear how to implement this.

My app is behind a secure login page and once logged in each user is signed in to a tenant (company) and has a user ID.  I want filter the activity for a particular tenant and / or user.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code the tag manager had me insert after setting it up (redacted my account into):

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XYZ-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Here is what I had before (the existing js and config tags) and added the additional 4 tags at the end).  The <%= %> are Rails code tags.:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-B0KXZBVWXH">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXX');

  gtag('company_id', '<%= current_company.id %>');
  gtag('company_name', '<%= current_company.name %>');
  gtag('user_id', '<%= current_user.id %>');
  gtag('username', '<%= current_user.name_full %>');
</script>
```

Here is my tag manager page:

[image]

I am trying to push this info to GA.  I would like to generate reports etc and get a handle on which users and clients are using the site.

Comment: Your app is a website or an Android/iOS app? Your Analytics code is like this UA-XXXXX-XX or this G-XXXXXX?

Comment: G-XXXXXX - website

Answer (score 0):

With GTM, you have to create a Google Analytics 4 Configuration tag and use `Fields to Set` to set persistent parameter values for all pages that fire the given tag. In your case, to set a `user ID`, add a row to `Fields to Set` and set the `Field Name` to **user_id**, and the Value to a Tag Manager Variable that returns the user ID.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en

The value of the `user_Id` have to pass to pushed to the dataLayer, or written in the page (in a JS variable) and then retrieve it, when you know it after the user login.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I finally had a chance to implement this and not quite there.  I have `gtag('user_id', '<%= current_user.id %>');` in my head.  I am not seeing this data reflected anywhere on my GA dashboard.

Comment: In the tag manager the tigger is set once per page.